# Selecting Data based on a specific condition ,which is the optimal solution using sql statement or stored procedure using cursor in sybase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase, sap-ase

```
SELECT distinct(a.acct_num)
FROM customer_acct a,
     customer_acct_history b LIKE "%000%"
WHERE a.acct_num *= b.acct_num
  AND acct_type='C'
```

This Query would return a list of acct numbers from the tables. Based on this output . I am planning to run another Query and select various data from other tables . The second  query consists of various joins and also a Group by and Order by .I would like to  select only the top 1 data from this Query for every account number from the first query I didnt paste that here since it is a Big query .

I am planning to use a Cursor with a For Loop to do the Process. Is it an Efficient one or can it be done just using Sql statements aand Loops . Any Synatx would be helpful to complete the process with an optimized and time saving way .

Comment: Can you write this using explicit `join` syntax?  `*=` is not standard, and who can remember if it means `left join` or `right join`.  Also, what version of Sybase are you using?  Does it support `row_number()`.

Comment: It is an Left outer join .it doesnt support row_number .Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5 version @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you suggest some time saving way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temp table and assign all the account numbers from the first query.Put an identity column to your temp table so that its easy to loop through the table.

```
  create table #tmp_account(ID int identity not null,acct_num varchar(100)not null)
```

Now loop through the table using ID as the counter.

```
Declare @vc_id int     
SELECT @vc_id=1 
set rowcount 1
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM #tmp_account  )
begin
select @ac_nm=acct_num from #tmp_account where ID=@vc_id

-- put your 2nd query here..you can insert resultset into another temp table.
delete from #tmp_account where ID=@vc_id
select @vc_id=@vc_id+1
end
set rowcount 0
```

Comment: the Solution Goes ryt . but it takes really long tym for fetching a result output of 5000 rows from 15000 rows.can we add index to it. Is there anyway to fine tune and increase the perfomance .

Comment: when i use these statements as an SQL Query , It returns output for the first time . But it fails to display output for the second tym when we run this, without exiting form the isql. i figure there may be aproblem in vc_id any idea on how to proceed further

Comment: Can you try changing set rowcount to top as in select top 1 acct_nm... there can not be any problem with @vc_id as I have working proc in this structure. You can make ID as primary key,it will make the query fast.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of a cursor.

An example can be found here.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/in...ses/X61512.htm

```
declare c_account cursor for 
SELECT distinct(a.acct_num)
FROM customer_acct a,
customer_acct_history b LIKE "%000%"
WHERE a.acct_num *= b.acct_num AND acct_type='C'

@acc_num integer -- or whatever the column type is

begin

create table #foo ( col1 int, col2 varchar(255), col3 datetime)

open c_account 

fetch c_account into @acc_num 

while @@sqlstatus = 0
begin

insert into #foo (col1, col2, col3)
select top 1
col1, col2, col3
from
other_table ot
where
ot.col = @acc_num

fetch c_account into @acc_num
end

close c_account

deallocate c_account

end 
go
```

Hope that helps, but I suspect this could be faster if you do this as a series of joins.